# What happens when a thread tries to call both static and non-static synchronized methods?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class as

```
public class ThreadExample extends Thread{

    static int count = 0;
    public static synchronized  int increment(){
        return count++;
    }
    public synchronized int decrement(){
        return count--;
    }

}
```

Here I have one static method and one non-static method.

First thread1 have called method increment() which is synchronized.It acquires lock on class level.
Here my question is if another thread2 is calling decrement() method will that thread2 will acquire lock on decrement() and how it works?

Comment: `increment` is not `synchronized`, at least in the code you have posted.

Comment: As I'm not sure about it, I post it as a comment. My guess is that `increment` will use the lock on `ThreadExample.class` (instance of type `Class<ThreadExample>`) whereas `decrement` will use it on an instance of `ThreadExemple`. Thus, two threads might be running those two methods concurrently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `synchronized` keyword has two possible uses. It can be used as a *modifier* for methods, and it can be used as a *statement*. Besides, the `synchronized` modifier can be combined with `static`, and in that case the target object will be the enclosing *class* instead of the enclosing *instance*.

```
Scope    | modifiers           | corresponding statement
---------+---------------------+------------------------
static   | synchronized static | synchronized (X.class)
instance | synchronized        | synchronized (this)
```

If a method is `static synchronized`, the lock is acquired on the `class` object of the enclosing `class`, in your case on `ThreadExample.class`.
Although they're compiled into different byte code, the following two methods are equivalent:

```
public class Foo {
    // static method with synchronized modifer
    public static synchronized void foo1() {
        // ...
    }
    // equivalent synchronized statement
    public static void foo2() {
        synchronized (Foo.class) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

If a method is `synchronized` (without static), the lock is acquired on the instance itself. Although they're compiled into different byte code, the following two methods are equivalent:

```
public class Foo {
    // instance method with synchronized modifier
    public synchronized void foo3() {
        // ...
    }
    // equivalent synchronized statement
    public void foo4() {
        synchronized (this) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

So, `increment()` and `decrement()` are `synchronized` differently, and there can be a *race condition*.

Therefore, the variable `count` is not sufficiently protected from concurrent update.

`++` and `--` cannot be atomic themselves, as incrementing or decrementing a value requires a read-update-write cycle. Technically it could be atomic because some CPUs provide atomicity for that by providing corresponding instructions which will keep the bus / address obtained for themselves until the operation is performed. But the JVM does not rely on such things.

If you need a *atomic int*, you might want to look at `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`.

### How to do `synchronized` in C

`synchronized` is implemented with the VM environment methods `MonitorEnter()` and `MonitorExit()`.

### Pitfalls

When you use the `synchronized` modifier, you synchronize on something which is more or less `public`, i.e. visible to other objects and classes as well. The *Monitor* feature of `java.lang.Object` which provides the underlying facility for `synchronized` is `public`, as well as the native functions `MonitorEnter()` / `MonitorExit()` and the *wait pool* methods `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()`. This can lead to unexpected bugs and deadlocks if "somebody else" is also using "your object / your class" for synchronization.

Therefore it has become a pattern to actually not use the `synchronized` modifier but instead use `synchronized` statements on a `private` lock object, like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    public void foo() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now `Foo` can no longer be disturbed or blocked by somebody else synchronizing on it. You might think there might be a reasonable use case for that, but I think if you have a use case for locking across object / class boundaries, there's probably a big flaw in the design - things are not self-contained enough.

If you need a class lock instead of an instance lock, just make the variable static.

Note that when doing serialization, you will have to take care of the lock object. The simplest way is to actually not use Object, but this:

```
public class Lock implements Serializable {}
```

If you want to save serialization storage, you can declare the lock `transient` and recreate the lock during *deserialization*, but be careful about `transient final`, you need *reflection* or `readResolve()` for them, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 1):

Calling synchronized static methods tries to acquire the lock of the class object. (`ThreadExample` in your case), while calling synchronized non-static methods tries to acquire the lock of the particular instance object. So essentially you are acquiring 2 different locks and thus your code is not thread-safe. The data `count` may be corrupted due to race condition

Answer (score 1):

Oracle tutorial:

> You might wonder what happens when a static synchronized method is
>   invoked, since a static method is associated with a class, not an
>   object. In this case, the thread acquires the intrinsic lock for the
>   Class object associated with the class. Thus access to class's static
>   fields is controlled by a lock that's distinct from the lock for any
>   instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Static and instace level locks are two different locks and they are independant of each other.

Regarding scenario in question *"First thread1 have called method increment() which is synchronized.It acquires lock on class level. Here my question is if another thread2 is calling decrement() method will that thread2 will acquire lock on decrement() and how it works"*

even if thread1 is holding (class level)lock on increment method and thread2 calls decrement method it should aquire a (instance level)lock .

problem is not with aquiring the lock problem might start when they are trying to updated the shared variable.If two threads are trying to access count variable (one through static locking  and other through instance level locking ) at a same time then there might be a **RACE** condition between two threads.

As suggested by *Christian*  you can overcome this by using *java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger* instead of  *int*

For more details please visit [URL](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=35)

Answer (score 0):

A static synchronized method and a non-static synchronized method will not block each other. The reason is static method locks on a Class instance while the non-static method locks on the this instance— both actions do not interfere with each other at all.

In your code one method is static synchronized and another method is just synchronized. Your code is not thread safe, even if two threads are executing two methods on same object, one thread (executing non-static method) acquires object level lock and proceed. Another thread executing static method acquires class level lock (i.e. ThreadExample.class ) and proceeds. Remember that static methods are always class level.

To make your code thread safe you need to have below changes in your example.

```
       public static synchronized int decrement(){
           return count--;
        }
```